# The string '0000-00-00' is not a valid AllXsd value

Tags: azure, azure-logic-apps, bapi

I am calling a SAP BAPI in the logic app. I have several date fields as input parameters which does not need a value to be passed. So all the date fields are being sent as blank (in postman).

When the logic app calls the SAP BAPI all the date fields are defaulted to 0000-00-00. and I get the error

> The string '0000-00-00' is not a valid AllXsd value.

I also tried to change the type in schema to date , but that does not help either.

[image]

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BChOp.png)
[image]
[image]

Answer (score 0):

The error is occuring as the date had been defaulted 0000-00-00.

Receive the date as a string.

```
"DLV_DATE":
{
"type": "string"
}
```

Handle for the blank values (0000-00-00).

Rather than being defaulted 0000-00-00 - you can perform a check and if it is null, you can set it to  current date and pass it subsequently in the next step

Comment: . I am just sending in a blank data now in my json payload. But the date field "is a part" of the xml and need to be there.  I get this error now. 'The string '' is not a valid AllXsd value.'."

Comment: If I understand correctly, You are converting JSON to XML  using logic app subsequently passing to SAP API - or is it the opposite way? Can you also attach a screenshot in which action you are receiving the error ? Also, if my first line understanding is correct - can you pls let me know - for the blank data -what should be filled while processing - as it is a part of xml ? should null be passed or a pre-defined default value should be passed ?

Comment: Satya : In my logic app i am calling SAP API. I am passing values to the API by XML( that's how azure logic app accepts). But when i test in postman with the http url generated from logic app , i pass a json payload.